# Is it safe to use Proc with the same name as Iterator in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

I would like to define `proc` with the same name as `iterator` to be able to write short code `table.keys.sorted`.

And it seems Nim support that and resolve naming conflict correctly.

Is this an official feature of Nim that's going to be supported in future versions? Is it safe to use such approach?

Example

```
import tables, algorithm

var table = init_table[string, int]()
table["b"] = 2
table["a"] = 1

# Proc with same name as Iterator
proc keys*[K, V](table: Table[K, V]): seq[K] =
  for k in table.keys: result.add k

# Nim properly resolves `keys` as `proc` and not as `iterator`
echo table.keys.sorted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you can define an iterator and a proc with same signature is currently regarded as design mistake (see [issue #8901](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/8901)) but it will probably stick for a while.

Other options for your request of having short code are:

`echo toSeq(table.keys).sorted`

this uses `toSeq` from `sequtils` and unfortunately you cannot use UFCS with that (see [github issue](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/13595)).

Another option (actually on top of that) would be to define a `template sortedKeys` that does the above .

Or you could argue that this is not a design mistake and we could think of it as a feature that allows you to use keys of a table as a sequence. :)

Comment: Thanks, yea, I think it's better to keep that feature until someone invent a better way to allow function chaining etc. :).